# How to modify a function for different dim?

Tags: r

I have got a function which was used for his data `dim(1000*1000)`.My data are the same but with different `dim (500*1300)`.How Can I adapt the function to my dims?

```
 image.arr = array(dim = c(1000, 1000, 20)))
 interpolated.lst = vector(mode = "list", length = 1000)
 system.time(
 {
    for(i in 1:1200){
        interpolated.lst[[i]] = 
            apply(image.arr[i, , ], 1,
                  FUN = function(x){
                      imageSpline(x = dates, y = x, xout = 1:365)$y
                  }
                  )
    }
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses `apply` to go over the rows of the images, hence only the width needs to be provided. Just replace this:

```
interpolated.lst = vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(image.arr))

system.time(
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(image.arr))) {
        interpolated.lst[[i]] = 
            apply(image.arr[i, , ], 1,
                  FUN = function(x) imageSpline(x = dates, y = x, xout = 1:365)$y)
    })
```

Comment: @temor You must be doing something wrong — it works for me, and gives me the right answer.

Comment: @temor Apologies, indeed. It should be `nrow`, not `ncol`.